# Could not find gem byebug (> = 0) no Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quando executo o comando `rails server`, aparece-me a seguinte mensagem:

> Could not find gem byebug (> = 0)

Isto no Windows. Tentei utilizar um `gem install byebug` mas não funciona e no Linux esta com a seguinte mensagem:

> could not find gem rails

com a versão do `Ruby 1.9` e o `Rails 2.4`. Alguém me poderia ajudar por favor, sou novo em Ruby.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

No github do projeto, diz que esta gem requer uma versão mais recente do Ruby, `MRI 2.0.0` ou superior, mas recomenda para `Ruby 1.9` o uso da gem 'debugger'<sup>[byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)</sup>

> **Requirements**
>
> Required: MRI 2.0.0 or higher.
>   For debugging ruby 1.9.3 or older,use debugger.
>
> **Recommended**:
>
> MRI 2.1.7 or higher.
>   MRI 2.2.3 or higher.